# I am receiving this error "ValueError: Shapes (None, 256, 256, 2) and (None, 256, 256, 1)are incompatible while trying to train model for segmentation

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, image-segmentation

I am working on an image segmentation(TensorFlow) problem. The training images in the dataset are 50 and testing images are 51, while training my model I am receiving the following error

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 256, 256, 2) and (None, 256, 256, 1) are incompatible
```

The training code is:

```
model = build_model(input_shape)
model.compile(
        loss="binary_crossentropy",
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr),
        metrics=[
            tf.keras.metrics.MeanIoU(num_classes=2),
            tf.keras.metrics.Recall(),
            tf.keras.metrics.Precision()
        ]
    )
```

MODEL:

```
def build_model(shape):
    inputs = Input(shape)
    x, skip_1 = encoder1(inputs)
    x = ASPP(x, 64)
    x = decoder1(x, skip_1)
    outputs1 = output_block(x)

    x = inputs * outputs1

    x, skip_2 = encoder2(x)
    x = ASPP(x, 64)
    x = decoder2(x, skip_1, skip_2)
    outputs2 = output_block(x)
    outputs = Concatenate()([outputs1, outputs2])

    model = Model(inputs, outputs)
    return model

if __name__ == "__main__":
    model = build_model((256, 256, 3))
    model.summary()
```

Trace error:
ValueError: in user code:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:855 train_function  *
    return step_function(self, iterator)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:845 step_function  **
    outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1285 run
    return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2833 call_for_each_replica
    return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3608 _call_for_each_replica
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:838 run_step  **
    outputs = model.train_step(data)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:800 train_step
    self.compiled_metrics.update_state(y, y_pred, sample_weight)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:460 update_state
    metric_obj.update_state(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=mask)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py:86 decorated
    update_op = update_state_fn(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py:177 update_state_fn
    return ag_update_state(*args, **kwargs)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/metrics.py:1462 update_state  **
    sample_weight=sample_weight)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/utils/metrics_utils.py:366 update_confusion_matrix_variables
    y_pred.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(y_true.shape)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:1161 assert_is_compatible_with
    raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

ValueError: Shapes (None, 256, 256, 2) and (None, 256, 256, 1) are incompatible
```

I dont know what this error is referring to and at what point.

Comment: Can you also provide the model structure?

Comment: Yes, the build_model function.

Comment: Also, can you give where the error has occurred? Sometimes tf shows which layer got incompatible shapes. Since it's hight customized model flow it's hard to debug with a naked eye.

Comment: I am also facing this trouble,its not showing a layer. It just says the error which I have put in the quotation in above question

Comment: What is your input shape?

Comment: input_shape=(256,256,3)

Comment: Hmm, I tried but it's really hard to find the bug. I don't think I'll be able to help.

Comment: What do you mean"*at what point*"? Please post the full error trace (which, among other things, shows exactly where the exception is thrown).

Comment: I reckon the source of the issue is _squeeze_excite_block_ since you are playing with the axis there, but I'm with @desertnaut on that. Please add the "whole" error message to the post, not just the last line. It should be giving away more than that.

Comment: Please **re-read** [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as it would seem that you missed some crucial points the first time you read it, namely "***DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc.** - copy or type the text into the question*" (emphasis in the original).

Comment: Now you can see the whole (not image) trace error @desetnaut

Comment: I am using the Double U net model specified in the research paper named Double U net. I am not sure that the problem is with squeeze_ecite_block (part). And if u need any other info regarding the project to solve the problem, feel free to write in the comments if you need more info @desertnaut

Comment: Same fo you @merve , if you need more info